# how to transmit data from audiofile to environment via sdr?

Tags: transmission, usrp, software-defined-radio

I have a sdr-device, an Ettus USRP B200 and I was given the task to convey information from the audio file on the air . I have tried to do this through the program SDR#, but it only works on reception.

How can I achieve audio transmission?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The USRP is a kind of universal transmitter; it doesn't take audio and does a specific kind of modulation to transmit it over the air, but it takes complex samples representing a base band signal that represents the signal as you want to transmit it at the radio frequency.

You will have to use some kind of modulator that converts your audio file to a transmittable complex baseband signal.

Typical analog radio stations use FM (Frequency Modulation). There's plenty of options out there, but I would try to get the [GNU Radio live DVD](http://gnuradio.org/redmine/projects/gnuradio/wiki/GNURadioLiveDVD), which comes with GNU Radio, and that has examples how to do FM transmission. It's really [not that hard](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KWeY2yqwVA0) to create a FM receiver, and a transmitter is equally simple.